# How can I assign prop to data once

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an element

```
            <input
              type="text"
              class="text-[16px] text-light-text bg-main-background p-[11px]"
              name="email"
              ref="email"
              :value="emailInput"
              @keyup.enter="checkEmailAndSendCode"
            />
```

Now I want to assign prop data once to it

```
let emailInput = ref<string>("")
emailInput.value = props.form_data.email
```

Now I want to update it and show confirmation code block

```
const checkEmailAndSendCode = () => {
  // TODO: check email

  console.log('we are sending email: ', emailInput.value)

  // Require code for the new email entered
  requireEmailCode(emailInput.value);

  // Show email code block
  state.email.isNewEmailEntered = true;
};
```

Result: when I press Enter the emailInput is again populated not by the changed email but by email in props.form_data.email and old email is sent. Console.log shows value from props.form_data.email and not the email I input into form

What I want: I want emailInput to be populated from props only on start

Comment: You should use `v-model="emailInput"` instead of `:value="emailInput"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, instead of assigning the value of `form_data.email` to `emailInput`, like that.

```
let emailInput = ref<string>("")
emailInput.value = props.form_data.email
```

Just, set the value inside `ref` declaration parameter.

```
let emailInput = ref<string>(props.form_data.email)
```

And use `v-model` for two way binding instead of `:value` which the input value will not update with the update of `emailInput`.